# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract ServiceReference1.Service1Soap in the ServiceModel client configuration section

Tags: asp.net, web-services, endpoint

I have a problem really similar to a lot of other questions in this forum, but neiter of the solutions work for me - perhaps because I don't get them.

I have a VERY simple ASP.NET web service with just 4 simple methods. To test it, I connected to it from a newly created Console Application and it works absolutely perfect - just added the URL and had Visual Studio generate the client code (it generated 2 end points of which I needed to delete 1 in order to make it work, by I guess that's not important).

Then I tried doing the same thing in a User Control project (meaning that it's a class library). Then suddenly it throws an exception with a message like the on in the title of this questions.

I run the user control project locally in Visual Studio since it is still being tested.

I even tried copy/pasting the service model section from the other project (where it worked) into my app.config of the user control project - still not working.

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is the servicemodel section of the app.config file

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Service1Soap" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="Service1Soap12">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:49737/Service1.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="Service1Soap" contract="ServiceReference1.Service1Soap"
    name="Service1Soap" />
</client>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, after copying the serviceModel section from my Class Library to the ASP.Net website's web.config, I was still getting this error.

After some time, I realised you had to fully qualify the contract attribute of the endpoint, because the service is in a class library with a different namespace..

I.e. in the config where is says... contract="MyService.SoapService" etc You need to fully qualify this... contract="MyClassLibraryName.Namespace.MyService.SoapService".

Conor

Answer (score 0):

@kevin johnson : I am  not sure what do you mean by 'User Control Project'.copy pasting the service model configuration from working project to your app.config wont work,because when you have to use a web service , you either have to add the reference file with app config file which will be generated from *svcutil.exe* or by adding the web service to existing project as 'service reference' never try to alter the configuration file(app.config or web.config ) unless you know what your doing.

Comment: I understand, but simply adding the service URL through "Add Service Reference" doesn't change the situation - it still throws the error. 

Inspecting the generated code in App.Config reveals that endpoints have been generated. I just mentioned as a comment that I couldn't call the service from the "working project" before I removed one of the end points my self.

Comment: @KevinJohnson : can u share your config file of your application which is throwing this error

Comment: Okay, I think I found the problem: 

Adding a break point before the line of code that calls the web service and looking into AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("APP_CONFIG_FILE").ToString() reveals the path of the app.config file that the program uses.

In my case, this file was NOT located where it said it should be, so I created it and copied the contents of the app.config file from my Visual Studio Project to it and then it worked.

So, I guess now the question is - how do I get the program to use the app.config file that I have in my Visual Studio folder structure  in stead?

Comment: Using the opposite methods (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData) does NOT work and it's also not desirable to have a fixed location hardcoded like this. At some point, I need to publish my user control / class library to a server without knowing where it puts the app.config.